# Plot only specific dataframe rows that matches a criteria in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have a data frame built like this:

```
       Id        Client           data     
        1           5             25     
        2           8             63       
        3          13             42
        4           5             87
        5           8             35
```

and a array: `clients <- c(5,8)`

I need to plot a different **histogram**(of the data column) for each client that is in the "clients" array. In this example i would plot histogram for the client 5 with two bars(25,87) and one for the client 8 also with two bars(63,35). I think that i need to use the facet_wrap function to plot a histogram for each client, i also tried to do something like a for plotting for each client but didn't worked. I'm not sure about how i can do it so any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot on the same graph if there are limited number of `clients`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  filter(Client %in% clients) %>%
  group_by(Client) %>%
  mutate(Id = factor(row_number())) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Client, data, fill = Id) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

With facets :

```
df %>%
  filter(Client %in% clients) %>%
  group_by(Client) %>%
  mutate(Id = factor(row_number())) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Client, data, fill = Id) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') + 
  facet_wrap(~Client, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Id = 1:5, Client = c(5L, 8L, 13L, 5L, 8L), data = c(25L, 
63L, 42L, 87L, 35L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

clients <- c(5,8)
```

Comment: my data is in "time" format in this case minutes, and i'm getting an error because of that, do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: Is this colors(Id) based on the number of lines? I didn't understand that

Comment: The default `ggplot2` graph is really confusing to the point of being not suitable at all. Legend is meaningless, lacks a description of clients (oh, its there, but on the opposite side!), x-axis useless to the point of misleading and the font size is tiny. Not to detract from @RonakShah's answer, the look certainly can be improved (as can the output from `base::barplot`), this is more of a surprise as `ggplot` is often hailed as the best R's graphics toolkit, especially regarding the default settings.

Comment: @JediJesus What is the error that you get? Can you share sample of your actual dataframe? Yes `id` is based on number of lines maybe it needs a better name for clarification.

Comment: @RonakShah o fixed the error by converting the dataframe field to numeral. I wanted to do something... The values of the Y axis are the same for every plot (the one with facets), can I get a plot where each facet has its own values of the axis? I want this because not all of the datas are similar for each client, thus, some clients got really low bars.

Comment: Change `facet_wrap(~Client, scales = 'free_x')` to `facet_wrap(~Client, scales = 'free')`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just didn't do enough data-wrangling. Also, from your description, you need **barplot**, not a histogram (which would report counts of particular values in data, not their value).

This is a solution in `base`.

```
dt = data.frame("id" = 1:5, "client" = c(5,8,13,5,8), "data"=c(25,63,42,87,35))
clients = c(5,8,13) # for particular clients, or unique(dt$client) for all clients

# get data for every client
lst = lapply(clients, function(x){dt[dt$client == x, "data"]})

# unify length and transform into a matrix
len = max(sapply(lst, length))
mat = do.call(cbind, lapply(lst, "[", seq_len(len)))

# Put some nice legend
colnames(mat) = paste("Client", clients)

# plot this matrix with barplot
barplot(mat, beside=TRUE, las=1)
```

[image]

Comment: It says "can't find function sel_len"

Comment: @JediJesus I originally mistyped, but already fixed the issue. Please, try the code again.

Comment: the other answer it's more like what i need, it gives me a prettier plot i'm a simpler way, but thanks for your answer, It worked too!